# Embedding a youtube video in a mobile site works, but 'Domains protocols and ports must match' error is jamming browser

Tags: security, jquery-mobile, youtube, embed, mobile-website

I am trying to dynamically embed a youtube video into a mobile web page by injecting the following code via jQuery.

$("#tagetId").append("http://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0'  frameborder='0'>");

I am testing this on chrome ios and the video does render correctly however some part of the web page seems to think the video hasn't rendered and every half second or so I get a new instance of the following error.

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://mydomain.html from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

This seems to really jam up the browser and causes the the load event call back function (i.d. 'first line of code') to trigger over and over.

$('iframe').load(function(){
    //first line of code
    $(this).load(function(){
         //second line of code
    })
});

Is there a better way to do this. Can any one explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Since you're using jQuery Mobile, can you make a dialog? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/dialog/index.html

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it:

```
<iframe scrolling='no' class='youtube-player' style='height:200px;width:100%' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0?html5=1' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

Comment: Good old oHg5SJYRHA0!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you were doing with

> `$("#tagetId").append("http://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0' frameborder='0'>");`

but that looks like malformed HTML being appended.

Maybe you just didn't append the whole iframe tag?